# where can I find the database file and table files?

Tags: linux, mysql, fedora, rdbms

I installed *MySql* using :

```
yum install mysql-server
```

It is working fine from the terminal.I created a database named *music* and created some tables inside this database . Now I want to port the entire database to some other machine. How do I do that ?

In general where can I find the database files and the table files ? I searched a lot by the keyword *music* but couldn' find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I want to port the entire database to some other machine. How do I
>   do that ?

```
mysqldump -u root -p music | mysql -u root -p -h <other.machine.ip.addr>
```

> In general where can I find the database files and the table files ?

They are located in the `datadir` of MySQL:

```
ls $(awk -F= '/datadir/ { print $2 }' /etc/my.cnf)
```

Comment: can't I just carry the directory named _music_ under `/var/lib/mysql/` ?

Comment: Sure, you can. But what happens if you have changed the `datadir` in `/etc/my.cnf`?

Comment: and how can the method you mentioned, avoid this ?

Comment: It get the `datadir` in `/etc/my.cnf` instead of looking in default location `/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: `my.cnf` can also be located in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. you can quite savely carry the directory for a database from `/var/lib/mysql/` if you stop mysql before you do so: `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`. (although a dump is always the clean method, if you want to be safe)

Answer (score 0):

On Debian, the databases are stored in /var/lib/mysql. To port them, you can use `mysqldump -A -u root -p > dumpfile` and restore them in the new machine by `mysql -u root -p < dumpfile` or by copying the folders (don't forget to chown the files after transfert).

Comment: Except he's not using debian. But thankfully, the dir is usually the same.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what type of SQL engine you use. Probably InnoDB which stores all the databases in few files (usually /var/lib/mysql/ibdata*). So for the backup you will need to use `mysqldump`.

For **backup** use something like that:

```
mysqldump --hex-blob -u${BUSER} -p${BPASS} ${database} -r  ${BACKUP_DIR}/${database}.mysql
```

For **restore** copy ${BACKUP_DIR}/${database}.mysql on the other machine and execute:

```
mysql -u${BUSER} -p ${database} < ${database}.mysql
```

Of course don't forget to create the empty database first `CREATE DATABASE name`. Also as already suggested you can use `-A` with `mysqldump` but that will dump all databases.